# How can i open up a file and view it

Tags: java, file, io, jfilechooser

I know the following snippet does not have the functionality of opening a file for viewing.

```
JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();
    int option = open.showOpenDialog( this );
        if( option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ) {
            try {
              Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new FileReader( open.getSelectedFile().getPath() ) );
                //while( scanner.hasNext() )

            } catch(Exception exc) {
                System.out.println(exc);
              }
```

*This snippet presents a file chooser for opening a file*

In this snippet what should i do so that i am able to view the file *(as i double click it)*?

### It could be any file in any directory

Comment: what kind of file?  a text file will view differently than say a bitmap, or a spreadsheet.

Comment: ok - then you need to let the OS do this.  you will pass the file to the system as an external system call or use an API that wraps this behavior.

Comment: @ Randy can you please explain it with the code.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Desktop API: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
File file = new File("your_file.ext");
desktop.open(file);
```

Comment: @ tskuzzy what if this class is not supported on the current platform ?

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: Try it and find out. I'm not 100% sure of the answer to that. I assume the operating system will take over and give you the dialog where you select which program you want to open the file with.